# Differential Privacy on tabular data

Tags: machine-learning, differential-privacy

I wanted to create a deferentially private dataset of my private dataset. While I understand the concepts behind DP, I am unable to grasp how this can be applied to these fields. e.g.

```
email   timestamp  remoteIp     useragent   extUserReqType  
a@b.com 1614405118 68.237.20.83 chrome1121  IMAP
c@b.com 1614402004 78.127.10.15 safari8767  HTTP_OAUTH2
```

How do I calibrate noise for each of these fields?
If I just add noise, will the correlation between the fields be preserved?